# why memcached not support list, set or hashtable？

Tags: memcached

i think that there are many reqirements for this. 
for example, add a new post to a thread.
why no developer do this upgrade?
redis could do this, but the aim of redis is not same to memcache.
it is rare that redis is used as cache.

Answer (score 0):

Memcached *is* a hash table.  Depending on your needs, you can easily build a [scalable set](http://dustin.github.com/2011/02/17/memcached-set.html) implementation or just use it as a set itself.

Memcached is all about O(1) operations.  It's a multi-threaded app whose priority is predictability.  Any operation that can't be done in constant time isn't a suitable use case for memcached.